# calculations in Roll Rate in R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, hidden-markov-models

this should be my Expected OUTPUT: i need to use this for calculating the rollrate. by this code: i tried the below code but didn't worked out.

```
test_data$Group <- rep(1:5, nrow(test_data) / 5)
library(dplyr)
new_data <- test_data %>% 
group_by(Group) %>% 
mutate(D = (bal) /lag(bal, n=2)) %>%
data.frame()

OUTPUT I GOT: 
   date bal Group        D
1   1/31/2013  10     1       NA
2   1/31/2013  11     2       NA
3   1/31/2013  12     3       NA
4   1/31/2013  13     4       NA
5   1/31/2013  14     5       NA
6   2/28/2013  20     1       NA
7   2/28/2013  30     2       NA
8   2/28/2013  40     3       NA
9   2/28/2013  50     4       NA
10  2/28/2013  60     5       NA
11  3/30/2013  10     1 1.000000
12  3/30/2013  11     2 1.000000
13  3/30/2013  12     3 1.000000
14  3/30/2013  13     4 1.000000
15  3/30/2013  15     5 1.071429
```

expected output:

```
date        bal  D
1/31/2013   10   na 
1/31/2013   11   na
1/31/2013   12   na
1/31/2013   13   na
1/31/2013   14   na
2/28/2013   20   na
2/28/2013   30   3.00
2/28/2013   40   3.63 
2/28/2013   50   4.16
2/28/2013   60   4.61
3/30/2013   10   na 
3/30/2013   11   0.55
3/30/2013   12   0.4
3/30/2013   13   0.35
3/30/2013   15   0.25
```

please suggest: Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not clear to me - don't you already have the results you're after?

Comment: I have the results from Column D. i have that in excel, need to code it in R.

Comment: Is this structure repeated for different months?

Comment: yes .... every months, that the big problem. we need to select the one cell for 1 month and divide it by one cell from next month, this will be done for 24 months

Comment: is it possible in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have groups of three rows with the same date, we can use `dplyr`.

First we create a grouping variable called Group

```
test_data$Group <- rep(1:3, nrow(test_data) / 3)
```

Then we use `dplyr` to group the data, and then create the new column you need. It will save the results in the object new_data.

```
library(dplyr)

new_data <- test_data %>% 
  group_by(Case) %>% 
  mutate(D = lag(Balance) / Balance) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Comment: Hi Juan, 

Thankyou for your help, i tried it and i understood the code. But i have few doubts. 
I was able get the results, in my actual dataset the range is [1:14]
now i am only able to see first 10 rows and getting the message: 
... with 214 more rows

How can i view all the 214 more rows. 

I tried:  

write.csvtest_data, "xyz.csv")
read.csv("xyz.csv")

but not able get the column D in the CSV file. 

Also how can we save the below function into a variable. 


test_data %>% 
  group_by(Case) %>% 
  mutate(D = lag(Balance) / Balance)

Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: dplyr creates tibbles, that are a special type of data.frame. I have edited the code to adress this issue. This way you can save the results as a data.frame and then export it.

Comment: what if i need to divide 10/98, will there be a change in mutate function? which is row 4 divide by row 1 and the answere shud be at row 4, column D.

Comment: Yes, `lag(Balance)` is taking the value in the previous date, so you can divide it by the current one ( 98 /10 ). If you want to invert the operation, you can do `Balance / lag(Balance)`, for example.

Comment: Hi Juan, the calculations are not  coming  correct, please check my main question above, i have used your code and got the output.

Comment: You are getting different results because you are grouping by date `group_by(date)` instead of grouping by Group `group_by(Group)`. Try making that change and see if it gets the expected result.

Comment: thanks Juan, it worked. I have modified the question - As i'm Calculating the "ROLLRATE". What if i need to divide "25 / 98" and so on. how can we modify it.

Comment: You can add the following to lag: `lag(Balance, n = 2)`. In this case, `n` is the number of rows "before" the one ou are taking as reference. By default, `n = 1`, so you are currently taking the value of the date just before the current one, if you wanted to take a date seven days before, you'd change it to `n = 7`.

Comment: i tried with n=2, but its not working please check the main questions for exact output and the expected output. thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's probably a way to do what you expect, but that would be a different question, because the structure of your data is somewhat different and requires a different approach.

Comment: is there anything i could read to solve this ? any links or any functions or any document where i can find a solution for this question?

Comment: You can check this [dplyr Window functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html)